# .Net HttpClient - 403: Please enable cookies

Tags: c#, http, fetch, dotnet-httpclient, codepen

I am trying to make an HTTP request using the [CodePen URL extensions](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/api/url-extensions/) to recive the [HTML part of any pen](https://codepen.io/AdamDipinto/pen/MWWzgMa.html).

This works fine in the browser and also if you copy this into your `F12` console and run the following code:

```
fetch("https://codepen.io/AdamDipinto/pen/MWWzgMa.html")
  .then(x => x.text())
  .then(x => console.log(x))
```

> **Note**: If I use a proxy like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), then I get the same 403 'Please enable cookies' response as my C# HTTP example

But when I try it in my C# app with HTTPClient I get a 403 and a page back saying "Please enable cookies".
Here is a [.Net Fiddle to demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zYc9uy).
Here is the code:

```cs
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
        handler.UseCookies = true;
        using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36");
            Uri site = new Uri("https://codepen.io/AdamDipinto/pen/MWWzgMa.html");
            var response1 = client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,site)).Result;
            var content = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
```

> **Note**: If you use `F12` in your browser and inspect the cookies, CodePen adds the 'codepen_session' cookie.
>   I wonder if it is this cookie that the server cannot add in the C' HttpClient example, but can in the `fetch` example.

Any ideas?

Thanks

### Edit

The issue seems simular to [C# HttpClient blocked by Cloudflare](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/c-httpclient-blocked-by-cloudflare-when-fetching-a-certain-image/41143), I will contact CodePen themselves and will update this Question.

Comment: Please include all necessary code in your question and not behind some links to elsewhere.

Comment: The .Net Fiddle shows Console output so is more useful - I will update my question

Comment: @Longoon12000 I am using `handler.CookieContainer = cookies; handler.UseCookies = true;` and I would think that would do the trick - Perhaps the limits are too small?

Answer (score 1):

The error message I get in the .Net fiddle says that you need to do a captcha.

I expect that means you have a successful captcha cookie in your browser when you run it, but your .Net app does not, because it's not the same browser.

Comment: I think the Capture thing is a red-herring, it works with `fetch`. I have updated my question, in the browser, the server adds a 'codepen_session' cookie, maybe this is not being added in C# HttpClient

Comment: What happens when you run from the JS console in incognito mode?

Comment: It's the same, it still works okay - I think incognito still allows cookie, they just get deleted each time you close down

Comment: Then I would guess codepen is looking at the user agent and not allowing certain ones. Can you set the user agent in your .NET code?

Comment: I have updated my question with the `user-agents` header - No joy :(

Comment: I have run this from my command line, rather than in the fiddle and I'm still getting the capture error, not anything about cookies.

Comment: Thanks for your help - This this a Cloudflare security issue, I have contacted CodePen, but no joy, I have redesigned my project and I will no longer be using this method. The question can be considered closed.

Comment: Dear Luke you said you have modified your code. Can you advice what did you use ? And did you overcome the cloudflare 403 problem?